# yii2 framework use RESTful web services without enabling pretty urls

Tags: yii2

We are working on an agile project and we have to use the restful web services on the yii2 framework. But we can't change the URL system to the pretty URL because some actions are not working with it.

I have searched in RESTful web services documentation but could not find any solution for this.

https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/rest-quick-start

Recommended URL schema for RESTful web services:

https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/rest-quick-start#configuring-url-rules

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'enableStrictParsing' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 'controller' => 'user'],
    ],
]
```

Is there any way to do this?

More info about the api controller:

My controller is under the controllers/api dir. So full path is like;

> controllers/api/ContentController.php

Comment: What actions are not working?

Comment: All actions. I can not get it work like this: `index.php?r=api/contents.`

Comment: Did you tried to set `'enableStrictParsing' => false,`.

Comment: What web server - apache, nginx .. ? How is configured virtual host ? - show some code. Can your show some request code example and response headers? You need to provide more info ...